# Spring Security Roles в SPA (jQuery based)

Tags: jquery, spring-security, spring-boot

Подскажите с чего начать.
Задача: Имеется список пользователек с ролями (admin, operatoр, customer) 
У админа есть тоступ к редакции пользователей, Админ и Оператор могут редактировать товары, пользователь может делать заказ.
На данном етапа пока у меня реализация авторизации для всех:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
     if (user == null) {
            //LOGGER.error("No user found with username: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
        }
    Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet();
    roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(), roles);

    return userDetails;
}
```

Т.е пока забито статично для всех, но буду считывать роли с базы.
На фронте одна страничка html с секциями () где реализованы странички, при помощи jQuery показываю определенные секции если пользователь автиризован.

```
function loginUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let userData = {
        username : $('#formLogin input[name=username]').val(),
        password : $('#formLogin input[name=passwd]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url : "/login",
        data : userData,
        success : loginSuccess,
        error : handleAjaxError
    });

    function loginSuccess(userData) {
        saveAuthInSession(userData);
        showHideMenuLinks();
        showHomeView();
        showInfo(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    }

function showHideMenuLinks() {
    $("#linkHome").show();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
        // We have logged in user
        $("#linkLogin").hide();
        $("#linkLogout").show();
    } else {
        // No logged in user
        $("#linkLogin").show();
        $("#linkLogout").hide();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, когда создам разныe роли для разных View, какова примерная реализация по ролям? Я должен отправить ID роли в случае успешной авторизации и обработать ее и показать то что нужно для пользователя в зависимости от роли? Если ADMIN -> showHomeView(); showUserView(); и так далее? 
Подскажите пример реализации или есть определенные правила?

Немного модефицировал:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRole());

    UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(), authorities);

    return userDetails;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(RoleEnum roleEnum) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (RoleEnum userRole : RoleEnum.values()) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.toString()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/css/**", "/js/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
}

@Autowired
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

Подскажите как теперь вернуть в респонс клиенту роль?

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут не нужен jQuery и не надо получать токен из сессии есть jsp taglib

Вот мавен зависимость [spring-security-taglibs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs/4.1.3.RELEASE) и в jsp страницах используешь этот тэг для отоброжения контента в зависимости от ролей которые есть у пользователя, пример:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <h1>This message is shown for all users</h1>

   <sec:authorize access='hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")'>
      <h1>This message is shown only for admins</h1>
   </sec:authorize>
</body>
</html>
```

В этот блок `sec:authorize` можно ставить любой контент.